# What to do when a Net::HTTP response is cached and not the latest revision?

Tags: ruby, linux, http, curl

I am looking to use `Net::HTTP` to examine a response for a particular revision in the HTML taken from the remote server.

I loop over a `Net::HTTP.get()`, then, when the revision is noticed, abort script.

Is there a way that I can specify on a HTTP get to ensure that I am getting the latest available file, as opposed to building the response from some sort of server cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use `Cache-Control: no-cache`? See 14.9 in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.